# Using my saved ML model to work on a raw and unprocessed dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

I have created few models in ML and saved them for future use in predicting the outcomes. This time there is a common scenario but unseen for me.
I need to provide this model to someone else to test it out on their dataset.

I had removed few redundant columns from my training data, trained a regression model on it and saved it after validating it. However, when I give this model to someone to use it on their dataset, how do I tell them to drop few columns. I could have manually added the column list in a python file where saved model will be called from but that does not sound too neat.

What is the best way to do this in general. Kindly share some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

One can simply use pickle library to save column list and other things along with the model. In the new session, one can simply use pickle to upload those things in the session again.